# Is there a way to automatically create axios requests code samples for Swagger API Design?

Tags: axios, swagger, openapi, code-snippets, api-doc

I wonder if I can generate code snippets or axios request sample codes for Swagger UI on my API documentation.

Is there any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Swagger-UI supports code-snippets directly. You can do this in a Postman documentation collection or using an OpenAPI extension in ReDoc. https://redocly.com/docs/api-reference-docs/specification-extensions/x-code-samples/